# VIM: store output of external command into a register

Tags: vim

Is it possible to run an external command and store its output in a register?

- `:redir`  works for ex commands, not for external commands (afaik)
- `:r !`    runs the external command but directly inserts output into the
     current buffer

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to a user on the vim-use mailing list:

`:let @a = system("ls -l")`

To run a command with the file under the cursor as argument:

`:let @a = system("ls -l " . shellescape(expand('<cfile>')))`

Comment: It's wise to use the `shellescape()` function when building shell commands.  In this example, `:let @a = system("ls -l " . shellescape(expand('<cfile>')))`.

Comment: Also note that system takes a second argument which it pipes to the command as stdin, so you can e.g. yank a visual selection to a register and then pipe that register to the command `let foo = system("command here", @a)`

Answer (score 1):

`:redir` does seem to work, though a little clunky. If you're looking to pipe data from your file into the external command it may be easier.

```
:redir @a
:w ! ls -1
:redir END
"ap
```

EDIT: Interestingly, I just noted that it seems to be working for me in neovim v0.4.3 but *not* in vim 8.2.100 (MacOS 10.15.2, both installed via homebrew).