# How can I filter the content of a register in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to filter the content of a register (in my case, the clipboard register `"+`)
 through an external command before pasting it into the buffer.

There should be a solution along the lines of [VIM: store output of external command into a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694392/), but I just don't seem to be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

system() is the way to go. [`:h system()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/help?tag=system()).

You can use the old fashion way (the one that gives you a full control as you would be able to pipe and redirect as many times as it pleases you):

```
:let res = system("echo ".shellescape(@+)." | the-filter-command")
:put=res
```

However, you may have issues with line-endings (the last character needs to be *chomped*). Hence this second solution where vim uses a temporary file and pass it to the filter program:

```
:let res = system(the-filter-command, @+)
:put=res
```

There is also another way to accomplish this if you play with another buffer:

```
:new
:put=@+
:%!the-filter-command
:%d +
:bd
:put=@+
```

Last note: Vim already has a few filters of its own like `:sort`, `uniq` is also [possible natively](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/system-tools/trunk/plugin/system_utils.vim#201) (but a little bit more complex), ...

Answer (score 1):

```
:let @a = system("ls -l " . shellescape(@+))
```

Seems to work here.

Comment: that does not filter the contents of "+.
Also it is missing a ).

Comment: You're right I dropped the final ')'. Fixed. But it was working here a moment ago. Let me investigate... Yeah, still works. Are you sure "+ has a valid value when you're testing? It wasn't overwritten because you copied and pasted from your browser, for example? (I made that mistake myself.)

Comment: ah, Luc's comment made me realize what you were probably missing. I was using the same example format from the linked question. Yeah, just pipe or do whatever you want in the string you supply to system().

Comment: your answer still does not filter anything.