# How to simply ignore output from a program when called as an external one in vim?

Tags: vim

I can [dump the output content from my external command in the main window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726894/what-are-the-dark-corners-of-vim-your-mom-never-told-you-about/790218#790218), I can [disable "Press ENTER or type command to continue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890802/vim-disable-press-enter-or-type-command-to-continue-prompt) and simply [store it in a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694392/vim-store-output-of-external-command-into-a-register).

But how do I call an external command in vim (it can be any program, apt-get, etc) and simply avoid it creating a buffer window if an output? Simply IGNORE the output from a external command I ran? I just want to call the command from vim. The command starts a simple webserver (listening on port 8080) and I have to press ctrl+c to stop it and move away from the external command buffer.

I tried `silent` before `!cmd`, it works, but I would like to stop the process my external command created right after it was started.

**EDIT**: I changed my mind about the simple webserver. I another situations, just doing like the suggestion accepted answer it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipe output to `/dev/null`:

```
:!cmd &> /dev/null
```

Use `silent` as you mention to get rid of the `Press ENTER or type command to continue`:

```
:silent !cmd &> /dev/null
```

Read [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts) for more on hiding this message.

Comment: I've updated my question, it starts a process in background, how to I stop it right after I started? Your suggestion is going to help me in another problem I had, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Somebody When you say you would like to "stop the process", do you perhaps mean backgrounding the process? i.e. append an & after the cmd?

Comment: I think I'm doing the wrong approach and need to understand some concepts. The command starts a webserver and listens to a port. It doesn't make much sense what I'm doing as I've come to realize it, but your response indeed works to achieve what I'm asking in my question: ignore an output.

Comment: I've found a source with some good explanation about background process and your solution, I think you could edit your answer with it's information: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.editors/2006-08/msg00453.html Thanks!